# Why is there a difference between the same value stored as a float and a double in Java?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, precision

I expected the following code to produce: "`Both are equal`", but I got "`Both are NOT equal`":

```
float a=1.3f;
double b=1.3;
if(a==b)
{
 System.out.println("Both are equal");
}
else{
 System.out.println("Both are NOT equal");
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 28):

It's because the closest float value to 1.3 isn't the same as the closest double value to 1.3. Neither value will be *exactly* 1.3 - that can't be represented exactly in a non-recurring binary representation.

To give a different understanding of why this happens, suppose we had two *decimal* floating point types - `decimal5` and `decimal10`, where the number represents the number of significant digits. Now suppose we tried to assign the value of "a third" to both of them. You'd end up with

```
decimal5 oneThird = 0.33333
decimal10 oneThird = 0.3333333333
```

Clearly those values aren't equal. It's exactly the same thing here, just with different bases involved.

However if you restrict the values to the less-precise type, you'll find they *are* equal *in this particular case*:

```
double d = 1.3d;
float f = 1.3f;
System.out.println((float) d == f); // Prints true
```

That's not guaranteed to be the case, however. Sometimes the approximation from the decimal literal to the double representation, and then the approximation of that value to the float representation, ends up being less accurate than the straight decimal to float approximation. One example of this 1.0000001788139343 (thanks to stephentyrone for finding this example).

Somewaht more safely, you can do the comparison between doubles, but use a `float` literal in the original assignment:

```
double d = 1.3f;
float f = 1.3f;
System.out.println(d == f); // Prints true
```

In the latter case, it's a bit like saying:

```
decimal10 oneThird = 0.3333300000
```

**However**, as pointed out in the comments, you almost certainly *shouldn't* be comparing floating point values with ==. It's almost *never* the right thing to do, because of precisely this sort of thing. Usually if you want to compare two values you do it with some sort of "fuzzy" equality comparison, checking whether the two numbers are "close enough" for your purposes. See the [Java Traps: double](http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html) page for more information.

If you really need to check for absolute equality, that usually indicates that you should be using a different numeric format in the first place - for instance, for financial data you should probably be using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Very nice explanation, though it is possible for a carefully crafted decimal value to fail the comparison `((float)decimalValueAsDouble == decimalValueAsFloat)`, due to a double rounding.

Comment: @stephentyrone: Yes, I suspected it might be - although I haven't come up with any examples yet.

Comment: The only thing worrying me with this post is that it somehow gives the OP the impression that he can cast and use == if he doesn't understand the comments. 
Someone else posted this link: http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html which explains it quite well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: `1.0000001788139343` is such a number.  In hex, its value is `0x1.000002ffffffff...`; the two closest single precision numbers are `0x1.000002` and `0x1.000004`.  Rounding directly to single gives the slightly closer `0x1.000002`, whereas rounding to double gives `0x1.000003`, which is exactly half-way; when *this* value is rounded to single, the "ties to even" rule is used, and the result is `0x1.000004`.

Comment: @Fredrik, @stephentyrone: Thanks, will apply put both of these in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

A float is a single precision floating point number.  A double is a double precision floating point number.  More details here: http://www.concentric.net/~Ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm

**Note:** It is a bad idea to check exact equality for floating point numbers.  Most of the time, you want to do a comparison based on a delta or tolerance value.

For example:

```
float a = 1.3f;
double b = 1.3;
float delta = 0.000001f;
if (Math.abs(a - b) < delta)
{
    System.out.println("Close enough!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not very close!");
}
```

Some numbers can't be represented exactly in floating point (e.g. `0.01`) so you might get unexpected results when you compare for equality.

Answer (score 2):

Never check for equality between floating point numbers.  Specifically, to answer your question, the number 1.3 is hard to represent as a binary floating point and the double and float representations are different.

Comment: You would have gotten a +1 from me if your post wasn't filled with typos.

Answer (score 2):

```
float a=1.3f;
double b=1.3;
```

At this point you have two variables containing binary approximations to the Real number 1.3.  The first approximation is accurate to about 7 decimal digits, and the second one is accurate to about 15 decimal digits.

```
if(a==b) {
```

The expression `a==b` is evaluate in two stages.  First the value of `a` is converted from a `float` to a `double` by padding the binary representation.  The result is still only accurate to about 7 decimal digits as a representation of the Real 1.3.  Next you compare the two different approximations.  Since they are different, the result of `a==b` is `false`.

There are two lessons to learn:

1. Floating point (and double) literals are almost always approximations; e.g. actual number that corresponds to the literal `1.3f` is not exactly equal to the Real number `1.3`.
2. Every time you do a floating point computation, errors creep in.  These errors tend to build up.  So when you are comparing floating points / double numbers it is usually a mistake to use a simple "==", "<", etcetera.  Instead you should use `|a - b| < delta` where `delta` is chosen appropriately.  (And figuring out what is an appropriate `delta` is not always straight-forward either.)
3. You should have taken that course in Numerical Analysis :-)

Comment: The problem, fundamentally, is that while there are many `double` values which a particular `float` value could represent, the system performs a `double`-to-`float` comparison by selecting one a particular `double` value.  If I had my druthers, implicit double-to-float conversions would generally be allowed and implicit float-to-double generally prohibited, but floating-point operands could only be compared with precisely-matching types (some cases may require both operands to `float`, but others, `double`; neither is sufficiently dominant to be a "safe" default).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Java (and alas .NET as well) is inconsistent about whether a `float` value represents a single precise numeric quantity or a range of quantities.  If a `float` is considered to represents an exact numeric quantity of the form `Mant * 2^Exp`, where `Mant` is an integer 0 to 2^25 and `Exp` is an integer), then an attempt to cast any number not of that form to `float` should throw an exception.  If it's considered to represent "the locus of numbers for which some particular representation in the above form has been deemed likely to be the best", then a double-to-float cast would be correct even for `double` values not of the above form [casting the `double` that best represents a quantity to a `float` will almost always yield the `float` that best represents that quantity, though in some corner cases (e.g. numeric quantities in the range 8888888.500000000001 to 8888888.500000000932) the `float` which is chosen may be a few parts per trillion worse than the best possible `float` representation of the actual numeric quantity].

To use an analogy, suppose two people each have a ten-centimeter-long object and they measure it.  Bob uses an expensive set of calibers and determines that his object is 3.937008" long.  Joe uses a tape measure and determines that his object is 3 15/16" long.  Are the objects the same size?  If one converts Joe's measurement to millionths of an inch (3.937500") the measurements will appear different,  but one instead converts Bob's measurement to the nearest 1/256" fraction, they will appear equal.  Although the former comparison might seem more "precise", the latter is apt to be more meaningful.  Joe's measurement if 3 15/16" doesn't really mean 3.937500"--it means "a distance which, using a tape measure, is indistinguishable from 3 15/16".  And 3.937008" is, like the size of Joe's object, a distance which using a tape measure would be indistinguishable from 3 15/16.

Unfortunately, even though it would be more meaningful to compare the measurements using the lower precision, Java's floating-point-comparison rules assume that a `float` represents a single precise numeric quantity, and performs comparisons on that basis.  While there are some cases where this is useful (e.g. knowing whether the particular `double` produced by casting some value to `float` and back to `double` would match the starting value), in general direct equality comparisons between `float` and `double` are not meaningful.  Even though Java does not require it, one should always cast the operands of a floating-point equality comparison to be the same type.  The semantics that result from casting the `double` to `float` before the comparison are different from those of casting the `float` to `double`, and the behavior Java picks by default (cast the `float` to `double`) is often semantically wrong.